# Receive SNS push notification when objects in S3 changed

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, push-notification

I have a macos app where the user can upload files to his/her S3 buckets. I want the user to be notified by push notification through the app using AWS SNS when the bucket content changes. I am not sure how to do this. My thinking was (programmatically within the app):

```
1. create a SNS platform application ARN (e.g. arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:379221688515:app/MACOS_SANDBOX/Testapp)
2. create a SNS topic 
3. edit the topic policy to include : s3:ObjectCreated:Put
4. put notification with topic on s3 (putBucketNotificationConfiguration)
5. subscribe to the topic to receive push notifications
```

First of all, I am not certain my approach will work since I am under sandboxing and enabling the user to create his/her own push notifications for the platform seems optimistic. Instead, could I use the platform ARN I created using the AWS Console for my app for everyone else? Would that enable the users to be notified of changes to their own S3 bucket as long as I subscribed them to their own topics and buckets?

To test this I am having trouble with my first step where I don´t understand how to set the **attributes** of the platform creation. My current code is:

```
func createPlatformApplicationARN() -> AWSTask<AnyObject> {

    let sns = AWSSNS(forKey: self.snskey)

    let request = AWSSNSCreatePlatformApplicationInput()
    request?.platform = "APNS_SANDBOX"
    request?.name = "Testapp"
    request?.attributes=[]

    return sns.createPlatformApplication(request!).continueWith { ( task ) -> Any? in

            DDLogVerbose("SNS==> result : \(String(describing: task.error))")
        return task
        }
    }
```

I also am not sure how to set the policy for the notification (**s3:ObjectCreated:Put**). The rest of my code works for creating and subscribing to topics when I use the Console generated platform ARN.

Hope someone can help. I am using the AWS SDK iOS v2.5 modified to macos. T.

Comment: Are the files changing outside of the MacOS uploader app? Just wondering what you are notifying the user of.

Comment: Yes the files can change outside my app. This could happen if the user is sharing the bucket with others or uploading to it from different computer. The notification will enable the user to download the latest version of the files if not available locally